# Is request from China

Tags: javascript, c#, location

Can I determine from "**System.Web.HttpRequest**" in **C#** or in **JavaScript** if request is from China?

I found some solution using external library or make request with ip in params, but this resource have limits number of requests per day

I there any list of all ip from China or how I can to determine if current user is from China?

Comment: add the tag Timezone

Comment: there are lot of ways to detect the geographical locations!!1

Comment: Removed the time zone tag.  Has nothing to do with what was asked.  Time zone != location

Answer (score 0):

[MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs) has a C# API for its GeoLite2 database that you could feed an IP into.

Basically install the API, get some method of regularly updating the database, and query away.  Because you'd be downloading/updating the entire database, you query against a local copy on your server with no limits.  The only limitation is on how often you update (which is, IIRC, limited to once per day for the free DB--check their terms of service for details).

Only slightly convoluted, and free if you do it right.